# blazor event syntax with arobas or not

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I do not understand the difference between this syntax:

```
<button @onclick="@fct">
```

And this one:

```
<button @onclick="fct">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual preference for a human reader.

I personally prefer adding the @ symbol, helps me distinguish hard coded strings from variables

Comment: how should i do if i want to put a constant string which starts with an arobas (@) in a component parameter ? Thanks

Comment: You could put the constant im the viewmodel and concatenate it from there?

Comment: Or just escape it with a second @ symbol if in markup on server blazor? Maybe post a separate question with.a relevant snippet