# Blazor - using @ or not

Tags: blazor

Here: [SimilarQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441646/blazor-event-syntax-with-arobas-or-not), the accepted answer is that using `@` or not is based on esthetic reasons.

But in my use case there seems to be a difference:

```
<MudSelect T="int" Label="Add to meeting:" Variant="Variant.Outlined" @bind-Value="SelectedTaskId">
    @foreach (var task in TasksNotInMeeting)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="task.Id">task.Name</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
```

Using `task.Name` instead of `@task.Name` makes the output be "task.Name". The task.Id seems to work though. As I'm writing this I'm thinking it's probably because I'm on a html area, is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's probably because I'm on a html area, is that right?

Yes.

The 'Razor Engine', a transpiler, needs to distinguish between C# and HTML input. This switching has been made very smart and lightweight.

When Razor expects C# then an extra `@` is harmless (but clutter).

When Razor expects HTML and you want to show a C# value then you need to switch with an `@`. As in `<p>@task.Name</p>` .  The end of the C# expression or statement is detected automatically. Very long ago this had to be written as `<%=task.Name%>`

See [this link for the Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#razor-syntax) with escape rules and Explicit and Implicit expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the official documentation from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#markup-1

Extract:

> Component members are used in rendering logic using C# expressions that start with the @ symbol. For example, a C# field is rendered by prefixing @ to the field name.