# Blazor component EventCallback parameter notation

Tags: .net-core, blazor

Lets say we have component with a function callback

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<object> OnDateChange { get; set; }
```

And in the parent page we bind it to parent function and declare variable for its reference:

```
 protected async Task MyDateChangedEvent(object obj)
 protected MyComponent MyRef{ get; set; }
```

Why does both of these notations in parent component work the same and which one of them is correct? Does the `@` sign make any difference?

```
 <MyComponent OnDateChange="MyDateChangedEvent" @ref="MyRef"></MyComponent>
 <MyComponent OnDateChange="@MyDateChangedEvent" @ref="@MyRef"></MyComponent>
```

Comment: `<MyComponent OnDateChange="MyDateChangedEvent" @ref="MyRef"></MyComponent>` this should be enough. your second line is redundant.

Comment: `@` is the switch char in razor but also the literal code in C# naming: `var @else = 1;`. So `@ is allowed in front of any name. It is only effective when used on a keyword.

Comment: @HenkHolterman this answers my question, can you make it a separate answer I will accept it ?

Comment: OK, but there already is a duplicate for this. I'll add that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is the switch char in razor but also the take-literal code in C# naming: `var @else = 1;`.

So `@` is allowed in front of any name. It is only effective when used on a keyword.

Blazor (razor) uses it to switch contexts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903108/60761).

Answer (score 0):

@ is older blazor notation. You *can* skip it. However, there would be a problem if you try to pass a string.

Consider

```
<Component label="@labelProvider.Value" />
```

vs

```
<Component label="labelProvider.Value" />
```

the latter will be considered literally and cause problems.

Of course, it makes no difference on the event callbacks. But for the sake of consistency, you might want to use it everywhere.